# EF Code First - Cannot insert the value NULL into column

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

So I have this Code-First class:

```
[Table("Session")]
public partial class Session
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int SessionID { get; set; }

    public DateTime Start { get; set; }

    public DateTime End { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public int PatientID { get; set; }

    public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }
}
```

I use Migrations, and I try to seed the Sessions table in my initializer:

```
IList<Session> defaultSessions = new List<Session>();
defaultSessions.Add(new Session()
{
    Start = DateTime.Parse("09/01/2014 14:00:00"),
    End = DateTime.Parse("09/01/2014 14:10:00"),
    Type = "pharyngeal",
    PatientID = 1,
});
foreach (Session session in defaultSessions)
{
    context.Sessions.Add(session);
}
```

The SessionID is supposed to be the Primary Key, and Auto-Incremented, that's why you use `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` right?

Well still I get this error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column table column does not allow
>   nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated

The table in the database looks like this (Note I'm using LocalDB, and the database is under the instance `mssqllocaldb`:
[image]
What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
I noted that in the database, the identity is `FALSE`, see this screenshot:
[image]
This strikes me weird, because in the latest migration, I did the fix on the identity (it's just the class I provided in this question), and the file looks like this:

```
public partial class IdentityFixes : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropPrimaryKey("dbo.Admin");
        DropPrimaryKey("dbo.Session");
        AlterColumn("dbo.Admin", "AdminID", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
        AlterColumn("dbo.Session", "SessionID", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
        AddPrimaryKey("dbo.Admin", "AdminID");
        AddPrimaryKey("dbo.Session", "SessionID");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropPrimaryKey("dbo.Session");
        DropPrimaryKey("dbo.Admin");
        AlterColumn("dbo.Session", "SessionID", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        AlterColumn("dbo.Admin", "AdminID", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        AddPrimaryKey("dbo.Session", "SessionID");
        AddPrimaryKey("dbo.Admin", "AdminID");
    }
}
```

As you can see, identity is set to true in the fix. I did `Update-Database` so I don't understand why this doesn't work..

Comment: Have you tried running profiler on the database to see what query is actually being sent?

Comment: @MattC No I didn't because I don't know what you are talking about and how to do that. According to all the documentation I could find about Entity Framework, shouldn't this ought to work?

Comment: You could get a demo of EFProfiler (critical tool when working with EF), integrate it into your app (single line in Main) and look at the statements being sent to SQL. Your configuration looks fine so the only way to debug is to look at what EF is sending to the database. You may also try replacing `new Session()` with `context.Sessions.Create()`.

Comment: your property at CodeFirst is not available to set NULL. If you want ot set null, you can do it: int? k=null; Moreover, you should alter your database fields to allow to set NULL to your fields.

Comment: @QuantumHive Apologies, are you running against a database you have access to? Like SqlServer Management Studio?  If so you can run the Sql Server Profiler and actually see the queries that are being sent to the Database.

Comment: @MattC I'm sorry, I forgot to mention, I actually use LocalDB

Comment: @StepUp No, the property should obviously not be null since it's the primary key.

Comment: @QuantumHive if you have it available, SqlProfiler should word with LocalDB using namedpipe connection.

Comment: try this: [Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
 public int SessionID { get; set; }

Comment: On the properties for your SessionID column, is "Is Identity" set to true?

Comment: @MattC The `Is Identity` is set to false in the properties pane for `SessionID` column :( So the Code-First Approach here is not correct?

Comment: @QuantumHive So your column isn't set up the autogenerate an Id.  This looks like the table generation from your code isn't handling the attributes you've placed on SessionID.  Did you try sexta13's suggestion?

Comment: When do you generate the tables?

Comment: @MattC I tried sexta13's suggestion, which led to an empty Up/Down Migration. So that has changed nothing. I made an edit to my question, I did a migration before where it should suppose to set the identity to true.

Comment: Maybe migrations isn't performed before actually seeding the tables?

Comment: I tried another Migration Update where I changed `SessionID` to `SessionId` with lowercase `d`. But when checking out the database, it isn't updated..

Comment: `Update-Database -verbose`, make sure the startup project in the solution and the default project on PMC is the project that contains `DbContext`

Comment: Weird, I deleted the database entirely and also deleted the Migration folder, rerun my program and voila. Suddenly everything works just fine. I find this very odd. Maybe an extra note, the initializer inherits from `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` which is called in the constructor of my `DBContext`.

Comment: @YuliamChandra I did `-verbose` and apparently when doing `update-database`, the wrong project was targeted (the startup project was targeted) even though the default project and ContextProjectName was set to the project containing the DatabaseContext. Thanks, I think this should be noted as an answer for this question. And that I should investigate more on how to update my database from migrations in a different project.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60703/discussion-on-question-by-quantumhive-ef-code-first-cannot-insert-the-value-nu).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem caused by applying Migrations to existing database, so I created an empty Migration and use SQL code, here is my example:

```
public override void Up()
{
  DropForeignKey("dbo.Bar", "FooId", "dbo.Foo");
  Sql("IF object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_Bar_Foo]', N'F') IS NOT NULL ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Bar] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_Bar_Foo]");
  Sql("CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FooTemp] ([Id] int NOT NULL)");
  Sql("INSERT INTO [dbo].[FooTemp] ([Id]) SELECT [Id] FROM [dbo].[Foo]");
  Sql("DROP TABLE [dbo].[Foo]");
  Sql("CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Foo] ([Id] int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL)");
  Sql("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Foo] ON");
  Sql("INSERT INTO [dbo].[Foo] ([Id]) SELECT [Id] FROM [dbo].[FooTemp]");
  Sql("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Foo] OFF");
  Sql("DROP TABLE [dbo].[FooTemp]");
  AddPrimaryKey("dbo.Foo", "Id");
  AddForeignKey("dbo.Bar", "FooId", "dbo.Foo", "Id");
}

public override void Down()
{
  DropForeignKey("dbo.Bar", "FooId", "dbo.Foo");
  Sql("CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FooTemp] ([Id] int NOT NULL)");
  Sql("INSERT INTO [dbo].[FooTemp] ([Id]) SELECT [Id] FROM [dbo].[Foo]");
  Sql("DROP TABLE [dbo].[Foo]");
  Sql("CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Foo] ([Id] int NOT NULL)");
  Sql("INSERT INTO [dbo].[Foo] ([Id]) SELECT [Id] FROM [dbo].[FooTemp]");
  Sql("DROP TABLE [dbo].[FooTemp]");
  AddPrimaryKey("dbo.Foo", "Id");
  AddForeignKey("dbo.Bar", "FooId", "dbo.Foo", "Id");
}
```

HTH